# Forking run method in a model. What should the priority be?

Tags: multithreading, model-view-controller, smalltalk

I am making a small game in smalltalk, with a use timers. An object appears every second, and the game lasts 10. If i run a while loop for 10 seconds, i cannot capture any input from the controllers as well as display it in the view. So i have made a new process, but if i fork it as is, the run method has a too high priority and the others don't have a chance to run. Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT:

I have forked the run method at 49, and the controller and view work, but only when i move the mouse while it's over the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork a process but you want to process it through the regular window event queue.  Try something like this:

```
tick
   self doStuff.
   self gameFinished ifFalse: [
      [(Delay forSeconds: 1) wait.
         [self tick] uiEventFor: self builder window] fork]
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, forking off a process is not a good design decision to solve this problem. I'd rather make an action queue, where you put actions with a time stamp when the action needs to be performed. Then in each cycle of your game's main loop you remove all the actions that are due, and process them.

E.g. for an object to spawn every second you would add an action for 1 second in the future, and when processing that action it adds the same action for again 1 second in the future.

This would make your game much more predictable and debuggable than if you we're trying to do it with concurrent processes.